# How to properly place the title with an UnimasThesis abstract?

Tags: templates

How can i show the title `Segmentasi Automatik Imej Resonans Magnet Jantung untuk Penilaian Edema` above the abstract heading?
[image]

```
\begin{msAbstract}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{Segmentasi Automatik Imej Resonans Magnet Jantung untuk Penilaian Edema}
\end{center}


text

\end{msAbstract}
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{UnimasThesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{enumerate}


\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,columns=fullflexible,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,texcsstyle=*\bfseries\color{NavyBlue},
commentstyle=\itshape\color{PaleVioletRed4},
frame=single,framesep=6pt,
framexleftmargin=6pt,framexrightmargin=6pt,
xleftmargin=12pt,xrightmargin=12pt,
breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true}


\title{AUTOMATIC SEGMENTATION OF CARDIAC MAGNETIC RESONANCE IMAGES FOR OEDEMA ASSESSMENT}
\author{Amajd Khan}
\faculty{Faculty of Computer Science and Information Technology }
\facultyColour{6c7a8c} %% 6-digit RGB hexadecimal code 
\submissionyear{2017}
\degreetype{Doctor of Philosophy\\(Computer Science)}

% If using APA bibliography style

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}




%\usepackage{natbib}

%\bibliographystyle{apalike}



\newgeometry{top=3cm, bottom=3.00cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm}

%\usepackage{etoolbox} % "lipsum" for filler text
%\makeatletter
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
    {\parindent \z@ \Large
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \center \Large\bfseries \MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 3\p@
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
}}
%\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
%  %%%%%\vspace*{50\p@}% %%% removed!
%  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
%    \normalfont
%    \interlinepenalty\@M
%    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
%    \vskip 40\p@
%  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\frontmatter

\newpage~
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering \large \textbf{Automatic Segmentation of Cardiac Magnetic Resonance Images for Oedema Assessment} \par}
\vspace{3.8cm}
{\centering\Large Amjad Khan\par}
\vspace{3.8cm}
{\centering \large A Thesis submitted \\
    In  fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of \\
    Doctor of Philosophy\par}

\vspace{3.9cm}
{\centering \Large Faculty of Computer Sciences and Information Technology\\
    \textbf{UNIVERSITI MALAYSIA SARAWAK}\\ 
    2017\par}
% List of conformation may be prepared as in confirmation.tex
\input{confirmation}
% List of declaration may be prepared as in confirmation.tex
\input{declaration}

% Acknowledgements from ack.tex
\input{ack}



% English abstract from abstract-en.tex
\input{abstract-en}

% Malay Abstract from abstrak-ms.tex
%\input{ABSTRAK}




%\input{abstract-mal}
% Malay Abstract from abstrak-ms.tex
\input{abstrak-ms}




% LIST OF TABLE 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

% List of Symbols may be prepared as in symbols.tex
\input{symbols}

\mainmatter
% Each chapter from a separate file
\input{chap1-Introduction}
\input{chap2-literature}
\input{chap3-NEW}
\input{chap4-contoursegmentation}
\input{chap5-assessment}
\input{chap6-oedema}
\input{chap7-conclusion}
\appendix
\input{app-Guidelines}
%\input{app-code}
\input{app-results}


% references are listed in refs.bib
\bibliography{refs}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please show your question to a friend and ask him if he understands the question. I certainly do not. Where is `msAbstract` defined? It is some weird thesis template from a university? They probably designed it to be this way.

Comment: Have you tried to just switch your title before the abstract environment?

Comment: @Johannes_B yes i want to switch the title before the abstrack and in medium

Comment: Completely off topic: I see you are not a native english speaker, there is nothing to worry about it, but please note that it is *please* and not *plz*.

Comment: `\begin{msAbstract}[Segmentasi Automatik Imej Resonans Magnet Jantung]`

Comment: @Johannes_B ok thanks i use this code first then i will inform you

Comment: @Johannes_B the problem is solved but i need to show in center becouse it appear on right side.  Thanks

Comment: Amjad, it is centered. If it is not for you, something funny is going on on your side which we cannot reproduce. You have been asked about an hour ago to show a minimal working example, just like in your other question, and yet, you didn't bother to post one. I used google based on previous question by you, quickly looked into the manual of the template and provided you with a working solution. Now it is up to *you* to show the information we need to help *you*.

Comment: [What is a minimal working example?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and [How to create a minimal working example?](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html)

Comment: @Johannes_B I try to edit the main code then you will get the problem

Comment: I am a bit sad to see that you did not bother to follow the links i gave you. The example was not properly formatted, it isn't compilable and you reverted the earlier edits i made, including the correction of `plz` to *please*.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you very much the problem is solved.. I am so sorry to disturbed you..

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

From the manual of the template:

> `UnimasThesis` is a LaTeX class for authoring theses that fulfill formatting specifications required by the Universiti Malaysia Sarawak (Unimas), Malaysia.

Reverse any changes you made, for example the redefinition of `\@makechapterhead` and you will get the document as the university wants it.

From the manual:

> Note that if your thesis is in English, you will need to provide the Bahasa Malaysia translation of your thesis title as an option to your `msAbstract` environment.

```
    % The Malay translation of your title needs to be given here
\begin{msAbstract}[Segmentasi Automatik Imej Resonans Magnet
    Jantung untuk Penilaian Edema]
Inilah abstrak dalam Bahasa Melayu. Data korpus merupakan data bahasa
Melayu yang datangnya dalam dua bentuk sumber, iaitu bentuk tulisan
dan bentuk lisan. Bentuk tulisan seperti buku, majalah, surat khabar,
makalah, monograf, dokumen, kertas kerja, efemeral, puisi, drama,
kad bahan, surat, risalah dan sebagainya. Sementara bentuk lisan yang
ditranskripsikan seperti ucapan, wawancara, temu bual, perbualan dan
sebagainya dalam pelbagai bentuk rakaman.
\end{msAbstract}
```

[image: amjadUnimasThesisAbstract]

Comment: The heading need to show into 1.5 wile the other into double